# Libgdx, OrthographicCamera is not working(zoom-in,zoom-out)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i have a problem with libgdx.I want to make a simple example about zoom-in, zoom-out ,but orthographicCamera is not doing anything.

My codes:

```html
public class HitTheGreenBlock extends ApplicationAdapter {

    public static int WIDTH, HEIGHT;

    SpriteBatch batch;
    OrthographicCamera orthographicCamera;

    private StateManager stateManager;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        orthographicCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        orthographicCamera.translate(WIDTH /20 , HEIGHT / 20);
        orthographicCamera.update();

        stateManager = new StateManager();

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0.78f, 0.25f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stateManager.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stateManager.draw(batch);

    }
}
```

And the class that draws image to the screen:

```html
public class PlayState extends MainState{

    public PlayState(StateManager stateManager){
        super(stateManager);
    }

    private int width,height;

    public void init() {
        width = 2 * HitTheGreenBlock.WIDTH / 3;
        height = width;
        ImageLoader.load(); 

    }
    public void update(float dt) {


    }
    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {

        spriteBatch.begin();

        spriteBatch.draw(ImageLoader.greenRegion, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - width) / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 5, width, height);

        spriteBatch.end();

    }
    public void handleInput() {

    }
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

I send spriteBatch from HitTheGreenBlock.class to PlayState.class .

I changed  this line:

```html
        orthographicCamera.translate(WIDTH , HEIGHT);
```

to this line:

```html
        orthographicCamera.translate(WIDTH /20 , HEIGHT / 20);
```

But orthographicCamera doing anything and images size is not changing.

What is the problem in my code?

*I have 3 more class, if it is needed, i can add them too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the projection matrix to camera.combined on your spriteBatch? Before spriteBatch.begin, put `spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);`

Doing so will tell the spriteBatch to render relative to your camera.

Comment: I added that line ,but this time anything doesn't seem in the screen except background color.

Comment: Good. Make sure to always set the projection matrix whenever you draw things. Very important.